# Haskell IRC Bot Stalling Out

Tags: haskell, bots, irc

I know Haskell fairly well, and I'm writing an IRC interface for my bot. I have the following problem:

After running the code..

```
module Main (main) where

import Network
import Data.List
import System.IO

server = "irc.freenode.org"
port   = 6667
chan   = "#tanuki"
nick   = "DuckBot01"

main :: IO ()
main = do
    bot <- connect 
    run bot

connect :: IO Handle
connect = notify $ do
    h <- connectTo server (PortNumber (fromIntegral port))
    hSetBuffering h NoBuffering
    return $ Bot { socket = h }
  where
    notify a = do
        putStrLn ("Connecting to " ++ server ++ " ... ") >> hFlush stdout
        putStrLn "done."
        a

run :: Handle -> IO () 
run h = do
    write h "NICK" nick
    write h "USER" (nick++" 0 * :tutorial bot")
    write h "JOIN" chan
    listen h 
--
-- Process each line from the server
--
listen :: Handle -> IO ()
listen h = forever $ do
    s <- init `fmap` hGetLine h
    putStrLn s
    if ping s then pong s else eval h (clean s)
  where
    forever a = a >> forever a
    clean     = drop 1 . dropWhile (/= ':') . drop 1
    ping x    = "PING :" `isPrefixOf` x
    pong x    = write h "PONG" (':' : drop 6 x)

eval :: Handle -> String -> IO ()
eval     h "!quit"               = write h "QUIT" ":byebye" 
eval     _ _                     = return () -- ignore everything else

privmsg :: Handle -> String -> IO ()
privmsg h s = write h "PRIVMSG" (chan ++ " :" ++ s)

write :: Handle -> String -> String -> IO ()
write handle s t = do
    hPrint handle $ s ++ " " ++ t ++ "\r\n"
    putStrLn $ "> " ++ s ++ " " ++ t ++ "\n"
```

I get the following output in the terminal:

```
Loading package bytestring-0.9.2.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package transformers-0.2.2.0 ... linking ... done.
Loading package mtl-2.0.1.0 ... linking ... done.
Loading package array-0.4.0.0 ... linking ... done.
Loading package deepseq-1.3.0.0 ... linking ... done.
Loading package text-0.11.1.13 ... linking ... done.
Loading package parsec-3.1.2 ... linking ... done.
Loading package unix-2.5.1.0 ... linking ... done.
Loading package network-2.3.0.10 ... linking ... done.
Connecting to irc.freenode.org ... 
done.
> NICK DuckBot01

> USER DuckBot01 0 * :tutorial bot

> JOIN #tanuki

:cameron.freenode.net NOTICE * :*** Looking up your hostname...
:cameron.freenode.net NOTICE * :*** Checking Ident
:cameron.freenode.net NOTICE * :*** Found your hostname
:cameron.freenode.net NOTICE * :*** No Ident response
ERROR :Closing Link: 127.0.0.1 (Connection timed out)
*** Exception: <socket: 8>: hGetLine: end of file
```

Why does it time out? It's not my connection, my normal IRC client works fine. Help is appreciated.

Comment: simpleirc: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/simpleirc

Comment: Well, I decided to use simpleirc.... I really am not interested in getting technical. However, I'd like to know what's going wrong with my connection!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `hPutStr` instead of `hPrint` so that way your `\r\n` is rendered and sent to the server correctly. `hPrint` will give you the same output as `show`, which is not what you want. I recently made a bot following the Roll Your Own IRC Bot page, too, and I stuck with using `hPrintf`.

`hPutStrLn` automatically appends `\n` to your string, so you don't need to put that in your `write` if that's not what you want.

Also, you should change this bit.

```
return $ Bot { socket = h }
```

Your function is supposed to return a `Handle` but you're returning a `Bot` which you haven't defined. Just change it to `return h` and you should be okay there. (Since you've got it to compile, I'm assuming you fixed that.)

Answer (score 2):

Not 100% sure but I suspect your client is acting too quickly when it's connecting.

The IRC server should respond to the commands you're sending, but it isn't. The fact the IRC server sends you the ERROR line would also indicate that it's not a connection issue, but the IRC server is disconnecting you because your client is not behaving according to the protocol.

Try making sure that you wait for the IRC server to start sending data before your code sends the three lines it does.

Comment: I edited the code so now the 'run' function waits for the server to send three messages before sending its three commands. However, the problem persists.

Comment: @MagneticDuck please update your question with the updated code

Answer (score -1):

ummm the problem here is the port it's connecting to should be 8001 for irc.freenode.net not 6667 for irc.freenode.org.